# Ionic 2 ionScroll event to not refresh view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I add to the `<ion-content>` a ionScroll event which triggers the method `foo()` and in a `<button ion-button>` a click event which triggers `foo()` too. In my template I add for an example `{{ x }}` and the `foo()` method increments `x`.

The button click refreshs the view so that the new value is shown. The scrolling not. If I add a `console.log` this will print.

If i set the fokus to some element like a textbox or something, the view refreshs and the new value of `x` shows up.

have someone an idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because something very interesting and powerfull called **Zones**. If the concept is new for you, please refer to [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) and [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) for a great explanation.

As you can read there,

> Application state change is caused by three things:
>
> 1) Events - User events like click, change, input, submit, …
>
> 2) XMLHttpRequests - E.g. when fetching data from a remote service
>   Timers -
>
> 3) setTimeout(),setInterval(), because JavaScript
>
> … it turns out that these are the only cases when Angular is actually
>   interested in updating the view.

That's why the view is not being updated when you scroll, but it does when you touch any of the elements of the page (since it's a user event).

In order to fix this, one of the options is to let Angular know that it needs to be aware of some changes you're just about to make, because things will probably need to be updated. You can do that by running some code (the code that updates the `x` property) inside a zone, like this:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage {

    constructor(..., private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    public yourMethod(): void {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            // Update the x property here, and the view will be updated!
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the zones really helps me. If I understand zones right, its only a capsule for list of functions. And zones makes sure that the function all called before leave the zone? But why not using promises and stack the functions with then? `promise.then(..).then(..)`. And I thougth scrollin is an event...

Comment: The key is that zones are not only used to ensure the order in which some methods are going to be executed, a zone is a wrapper that allows angular to say _ok, do all the things you need to do behind the scenes, and let me know when I need to check the changes and update the view_. It's a very powerful concept because it can be also used to improve the performance of the app, by doing things _outside a zone (and thus, making them invisible to Angular)_ as you can read [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html)