# Auto-refresh LoadingController value

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am currently working on a Ionic project. In this project, I am using a LoadingController with a listener linked to the loading content.

But the problem is the following : the values refresh only when I tap on the screen, and I wanna make the automatically refresh.

The listener:

```
this.fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent) => {
  console.log(progressEvent);
  if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var perc =  Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
    console.log(perc + "% loaded...");
    loading.setContent('Getting video : ' + perc + ' %');
  }
});
```

The LoadingController:

```
var loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  spinner: 'crescent',
  content: ""
});
loading.present();
```

If someone knows why the value refresh only when I tap on the screen and how to fix it, I would be so grateful!

**edit** : The listener is checking the % of a downloading video

Comment: I think the issue is related to `NgZone`, you can find more information about it in *[that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474414/ionic-2-ionscroll-event-to-not-refresh-view/42477987#42477987)*.

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting the content in onProgress(), declare percentage as class variable , update variable in onProgress() and use it while creating loading controller.

`var loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  spinner: 'crescent',
  content: ""+variable
});
loading.present();`

Comment: Hello, This is what I initially did, but when I do this, it says that my variable is "undefined".

Comment: declare variable as public in the class e.g: class Page { public variable:any; var loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({ spinner: 'crescent', content: ""+this.variable }); loading.present();} and in 'onProgress(){loading.setContent('Getting video : ' + this.variable+ ' %'); }'